# Thousands of ORMLite raw inserts taking several minutes on Android

Tags: android, performance, bulkinsert, ormlite

I'm trying to pre-populate an Android SQLite database using ORMLite. The problem is that this operation is too slow. It takes several minutes. The code below show how it happens.

```
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Company, Integer> companyDao = ORMLiteHelper.getInstance(context).getCompanyRuntimeDao();AssetManager am = context.getAssets();

    try {
        InputStream instream = am.open("companies.sqlite");
        if (instream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //Log.i("SQL", line);                       
                    if (line.startsWith("INSERT INTO Companies")) {
                        companyDao.executeRaw(line);
                    } 

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("SQL", e.getMessage() + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("SQL", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Where companies.sqlite is a file with tousands of lines of inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO Companies (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Duff Beer');
```

I'm using a DatabaseConfigUtil class to avoid the use of annotations.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761472/ormlites-createorupdate-seems-slow-what-is-normal-speed/11762104#11762104

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a database transaction. See [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Transactions) and [TransactionManager](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.html). Something like:

```
TransactionManager.callInTransaction(connectionSource,
    new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            // Your code from above
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! A operation that, in the old way, takes four minutes, now takes some seconds!