# How change many records in an ORM database quickly?

Tags: java, sqlite, orm, ormlite

**Situation:** I need to change many records in database (10 000 records, in example), using *ORMLite DAO*. All records change only in one table, in one column and changing records, which have specified id.

**Question:** how update many records in database at once, using *ORMLite DAO*?

---

Now I update records, using this code:

`imagesDao.update(imageOrmRecord);`

But updating records in cycle very slow (100 records\sec).

I think that real update records, using SQL-code, but this is undesirable...

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a set-oriented language. The whole point of an ORM is to abstract this away into objects.
So when you want to update a bunch of objects, you have to go through these objects.
(You have run into the [object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch); also read [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).)

ORMLite gives you a backdoor [to execute raw SQL](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Statements):

```
someDao.executeRaw("UPDATE ...");
```

But if your only problem is performance, this is likely to be caused by the auto-commit mode, which adds transaction overhead to each single statement. Using [callBatchTasks()](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#callBatchTasks) would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: how update many records in database at once, using ORMLite DAO?

It depends a bit on what updates you are making.  You can certainly use the [`UpdateBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder) which will make wholesale updates to objects.

```
UpdateBuilder<Account, String> updateBuilder = accountDao.updateBuilder();
// update the password to be "none"
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("password", "none");
// only update the rows where password is null
updateBuilder.where().isNull(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME);
updateBuilder.update();
```

Or something like:

```
// update hasDog boolean to true if dogC > 0
updateBuilder.updateColumnExpression("hasDog", "dogC > 0");
```

You should be able to accomplish a large percentage of the updates that you would do using raw SQL this way.

But if you need to make per-entity updates then you will need to do `dao.update(...)` for each one.  What I'd do then is to do it in a transaction to make the updates go faster.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885274/179850).